# Solidus ecommerce Internationalization - Change labels with country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solidus

I want to change form labels in my Solidus ecommerce application.

My particular use case is handling UK addresses where the name "Zip Code" should be changed to "Post Code" - but there could be other localization changes as well.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Solidus](https://solidus.io/), which was forked from [Spree](https://spreecommerce.com/), provides a number of ways to customize the application. In this case you want to translate a string depending on the locale.

[Solidus provides a internationalization gem solidus_i18n](https://github.com/solidusio-contrib/solidus_i18n) for this issue.

Installation Instructions are currently (but check with gem readme):

```
gem 'solidus_i18n', github: 'solidusio-contrib/solidus_i18n', branch: 'master'

bundle install

bin/rails g solidus_i18n:install
```

You can also set the default locale within `config/initializers/spree.rb`

```
Spree::Frontend::Config.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.locale = 'en-GB'
end

Spree::Backend::Config.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.locale = 'en-GB'
end
```

#### Further Reading

[Spree Documentation on Internationalization](https://github.com/solidusio-contrib/solidus_i18n) - very similar documenation